# Is there a way to configure permissions, ownership and ACLs on /etc/fstab mounted NTFS-3g partitions during runtime?

Tags: permissions, fstab, ntfs-3g

```
 ntfs-3g         locale=en_US.utf8,inherit,big_writes,windows_names,nofail,uid=1002,gid=1002,umask=000,auto,acl,suid,async,user,rw,noexec,nodev  0       2
```

My initial goal was to enable SGID or an ACL but it seems like it's not possible to do this. Although, I can set the umask for the 4th bit, it doesn't seem to do anything. Once logged in to the system, I cannot change anything with regards to ownership and permissions within the NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 0):

ACLs are not supported for FUSE mount points yet: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/issues/4